# When I do a pod install in ReactNative, this log occurs. Is this normal?

Tags: ios, react-native

When you do 'pod install' in reactNative, the following log is returned:
[image]

When building iOS, the above error occurs and the build does not work.
Can you tell me what the problem is?

```
ui-MacBookPro-2 ios % pod install 
(node:13866) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[VisionCamera] node modules found at /Users/madol/project/ciriusPetClient/node_modules/react-native/..
[VisionCamera] react-native-worklets-core not found, Frame Processors disabled!
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `test`: RNGestureHandler, RNPermissions, RNSVG, RNScreens, RNVectorIcons, VisionCamera, react-native-compressor, react-native-date-picker, react-native-image-picker, react-native-netinfo, react-native-safe-area-context, and react-native-video
Framework build type is static library
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
[Codegen] generating an empty RCTThirdPartyFabricComponentsProvider
Analyzing dependencies
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
[Codegen] Found rncore
[VisionCamera] node modules found at /Users/madol/project/ciriusPetClient/node_modules/react-native/..
[VisionCamera] react-native-worklets-core not found, Frame Processors disabled!
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Setting USE_HERMES build settings
Setting REACT_NATIVE build settings
Setting CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD to c++20 on /Users/madol/project/ciriusPetClient/ios/test.xcodeproj
Pod install took 9 [s] to run
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 85 dependencies from the Podfile and 73 total pods installed.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `13.4` on target `test` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

[!] [Xcodeproj] Generated duplicate UUIDs:

PBXBuildFile -- Pods.xcodeproj/targets/buildConfigurationList:buildConfigurations:baseConfigurationReference:|,buildSettings:|,displayName:|,isa:|,name:|,,baseConfigurationReference:|,buildSettings:|,displayName:|,isa:|,name:|,,defaultConfigurationIsVisible:0,defaultConfigurationName:Release,displayName:ConfigurationList,isa:XCConfigurationList,,buildPhases:buildActionMask:2147483647,displayName:[CP-User] Generate Specs,files:,inputPaths:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,isa:PBXShellScriptBuildPhase,name:[CP-User] Generate Specs,outputPaths:|,|,|,runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing:0,shellPath:/bin/sh,shellScript:pushd "$PODS_ROOT/../" > /dev/null
RCT_SCRIPT_POD_INSTALLATION_ROOT=$(pwd)
popd >/dev/null

export RCT_SCRIPT_RN_DIR=${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/../..
export RCT_SCRIPT_LIBRARY_NAME=FBReactNativeSpec
export RCT_SCRIPT_OUTPUT_DIR=$RCT_SCRIPT_POD_INSTALLATION_ROOT/build/generated/ios
export RCT_SCRIPT_LIBRARY_TYPE=modules
export RCT_SCRIPT_JS_SRCS_PATTERN=Native*.js
export RCT_SCRIPT_JS_SRCS_DIR=../../Libraries
export RCT_SCRIPT_CODEGEN_MODULE_DIR=build/generated/ios/.
export RCT_SCRIPT_CODEGEN_COMPONENT_DIR=build/generated/ios/react/renderer/components
export RCT_SCRIPT_FILE_LIST="[\"../../Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/NativeActionSheetManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/Alert/NativeAlertManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedHelper.js\", \"../../Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedModule.js\", \"../../Libraries/Animated/NativeAnimatedTurboModule.js\", \"../../Libraries/AppState/NativeAppState.js\", \"../../Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js\", \"../../Libraries/Blob/NativeBlobModule.js\",
```

"../../Libraries/WebPerformance/**mocks**/NativePerformanceObserver.js", "../../Libraries/WebSocket/NativeWebSocketModule.js"]"

```
SCRIPT_PHASES_SCRIPT="$RCT_SCRIPT_RN_DIR/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.sh"
WITH_ENVIRONMENT="$RCT_SCRIPT_RN_DIR/scripts/xcode/with-environment.sh"
/bin/sh -c "$WITH_ENVIRONMENT $SCRIPT_PHASES_SCRIPT"
,,dependencies:displayName:RCT-Folly,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:|,displayName:|,isa:|,proxyType:|,remoteGlobalIDString:|,remoteInfo:|,,,displayName:RCTRequired,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:|,displayName:|,isa:|,proxyType:|,remoteGlobalIDString:|,remoteInfo:|,,,displayName:RCTTypeSafety,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:|,displayName:|,isa:|,proxyType:|,remoteGlobalIDString:|,remoteInfo:|,,,displayName:React-Core,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:|,displayName:|,isa:|,proxyType:|,remoteGlobalIDString:|,remoteInfo:|,,,displayName:React-jsi,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:|,displayName:|,isa:|,proxyType:|,remoteGlobalIDString:|,remoteInfo:|,,,displayName:ReactCommon,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:|,displayName:|,isa:|,proxyType:|,remoteGlobalIDString:|,remoteInfo:|,,,displayName:FBReactNativeSpec,isa:PBXAggregateTarget,name:FBReactNativeSpec,/dependencies/displayName:RCTTypeSafety,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:46EB2E00000000,displayName:ContainerItemProxy,isa:PBXContainerItemProxy,proxyType:1,remoteGlobalIDString:46EB2E00017330,remoteInfo:RCTTypeSafety,,/target/dependencies/displayName:React-Core,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:46EB2E00000000,displayName:ContainerItemProxy,isa:PBXContainerItemProxy,proxyType:1,remoteGlobalIDString:46EB2E000188E0,remoteInfo:React-Core,,/target/dependencies/displayName:Yoga,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:46EB2E00000000,displayName:ContainerItemProxy,isa:PBXContainerItemProxy,proxyType:1,remoteGlobalIDString:46EB2E00020000,remoteInfo:Yoga,,/target/buildPhases/buildActionMask:2147483647,displayName:Headers,files:displayName:Align.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Baseline.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:BoundAxis.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Cache.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:CalculateLayout.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:FlexDirection.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:FlexLine.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:PixelGrid.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:ResolveValue.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:BitCast.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:NumericBitfield.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Config.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:AssertFatal.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Log.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:NodeToString.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Align.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Dimension.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Direction.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Display.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Edge.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Errata.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:ExperimentalFeature.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:FlexDirection.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Gutter.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Justify.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:LogLevel.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:MeasureMode.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:NodeType.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Overflow.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:PositionType.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:PrintOptions.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Unit.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Wrap.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:YogaEnums.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:event.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:CachedMeasurement.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:LayoutResults.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Node.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Comparison.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:FloatOptional.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:CompactValue.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Style.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:YGEnums.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,name:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:YGMacros.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,name:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:YGValue.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,name:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Yoga-internal.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,name:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Yoga.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,name:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Yoga-umbrella.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,isa:PBXHeadersBuildPhase,runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing:0,/files/displayName:Align.h,fileRef:displayName:Align.h,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:sourcecode.c.h,path:Align.h,sourceTree:<group>,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:Project,,
PBXBuildFile -- Pods.xcodeproj/targets/buildConfigurationList:buildConfigurations:baseConfigurationReference:|,buildSettings:|,displayName:|,isa:|,name:|,,baseConfigurationReference:|,buildSettings:|,displayName:|,isa:|,name:|,,defaultConfigurationIsVisible:0,defaultConfigurationName:Release,displayName:ConfigurationList,isa:XCConfigurationList,,buildPhases:buildActionMask:2147483647,displayName:[CP-User] Generate Specs,files:,inputPaths:|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,|,isa:PBXShellScriptBuildPhase,name:[CP-User] Generate Specs,outputPaths:|,|,|,runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing:0,shellPath:/bin/sh,shellScript:pushd "$PODS_ROOT/../" > /dev/null
RCT_SCRIPT_POD_INSTALLATION_ROOT=$(pwd)
popd >/dev/null

export RCT_SCRIPT_RN_DIR=${PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT}/../..
export RCT_SCRIPT_LIBRARY_NAME=FBReactNativeSpec
export RCT_SCRIPT_OUTPUT_DIR=$RCT_SCRIPT_POD_INSTALLATION_ROOT/build/generated/ios
export RCT_SCRIPT_LIBRARY_TYPE=modules
export RCT_SCRIPT_JS_SRCS_PATTERN=Native*.js
export RCT_SCRIPT_JS_SRCS_DIR=../../Libraries
export RCT_SCRIPT_CODEGEN_MODULE_DIR=build/generated/ios/.
export RCT_SCRIPT_CODEGEN_COMPONENT_DIR=build/generated/ios/react/renderer/components
export RCT_SCRIPT_FILE_LIST="[\"../../Libraries/ActionSheetIOS/NativeActionSheetManager.js\", \"../../Libraries/Alert/NativeAlertManager.js\",.......... \"../../Libraries/WebPerformance/__mocks__/NativePerformanceObserver.js\", \"../../Libraries/WebSocket/NativeWebSocketModule.js\"]"

SCRIPT_PHASES_SCRIPT="$RCT_SCRIPT_RN_DIR/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.sh"
WITH_ENVIRONMENT="$RCT_SCRIPT_RN_DIR/scripts/xcode/with-environment.sh"
/bin/sh -c "$WITH_ENVIRONMENT $SCRIPT_PHASES_SCRIPT"
,,dependencies:displayName:RCT-Folly,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:|,displayName:|,isa:|,proxyType:|,remoteGlobalIDString:|,remoteInfo:|,,,displayName:RCTRequired,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:|,displayName:|,isa:|,proxyType:|,remoteGlobalIDString:|,remoteInfo:|,,,displayName:RCTTypeSafety,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:|,displayName:|,isa:|,proxyType:|,remoteGlobalIDString:|,remoteInfo:|,,,displayName:React-Core,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:|,displayName:|,isa:|,proxyType:|,remoteGlobalIDString:|,remoteInfo:|,,,displayName:React-jsi,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:|,displayName:|,isa:|,proxyType:|,remoteGlobalIDString:|,remoteInfo:|,,,displayName:ReactCommon,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:|,displayName:|,isa:|,proxyType:|,remoteGlobalIDString:|,remoteInfo:|,,,displayName:FBReactNativeSpec,isa:PBXAggregateTarget,name:FBReactNativeSpec,/dependencies/displayName:RCTTypeSafety,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:46EB2E00000000,displayName:ContainerItemProxy,isa:PBXContainerItemProxy,proxyType:1,remoteGlobalIDString:46EB2E00017330,remoteInfo:RCTTypeSafety,,/target/dependencies/displayName:React-Core,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:46EB2E00000000,displayName:ContainerItemProxy,isa:PBXContainerItemProxy,proxyType:1,remoteGlobalIDString:46EB2E000188E0,remoteInfo:React-Core,,/target/dependencies/displayName:Yoga,isa:PBXTargetDependency,targetProxy:containerPortal:46EB2E00000000,displayName:ContainerItemProxy,isa:PBXContainerItemProxy,proxyType:1,remoteGlobalIDString:46EB2E00020000,remoteInfo:Yoga,,/target/buildPhases/buildActionMask:2147483647,displayName:Headers,files:displayName:Align.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Baseline.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:BoundAxis.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Cache.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:CalculateLayout.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:FlexDirection.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:FlexLine.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:PixelGrid.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:ResolveValue.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:BitCast.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:NumericBitfield.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Config.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:AssertFatal.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Log.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:NodeToString.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Align.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Dimension.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Direction.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Display.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Edge.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Errata.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:ExperimentalFeature.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:FlexDirection.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Gutter.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Justify.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:LogLevel.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:MeasureMode.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:NodeType.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Overflow.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:PositionType.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:PrintOptions.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Unit.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Wrap.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:YogaEnums.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:event.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:CachedMeasurement.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:LayoutResults.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Node.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Comparison.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:FloatOptional.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:CompactValue.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Style.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:YGEnums.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,name:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:YGMacros.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,name:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:YGValue.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,name:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Yoga-internal.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,name:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Yoga.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,name:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,displayName:Yoga-umbrella.h,fileRef:displayName:|,includeInIndex:|,isa:|,lastKnownFileType:|,path:|,sourceTree:|,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:|,,,isa:PBXHeadersBuildPhase,runOnlyForDeploymentPostprocessing:0,/files/displayName:FlexDirection.h,fileRef:displayName:FlexDirection.h,includeInIndex:1,isa:PBXFileReference,lastKnownFileType:sourcecode.c.h,path:FlexDirection.h,sourceTree:<group>,,isa:PBXBuildFile,settings:ATTRIBUTES:Project,,
```

podfile

````
 def node_require(script)
  # Resolve script with node to allow for hoisting
  require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
    "require.resolve(
      '#{script}',
      {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
    )", __dir__]).strip
end

node_require('react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb')
node_require('react-native-permissions/scripts/setup.rb')

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'test' do
  config = use_native_modules!

 use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  pod 'react-native-compressor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-compressor'

  # ⬇️ uncomment wanted permissions
    setup_permissions([
      # 'AppTrackingTransparency',
      # 'Bluetooth',
      # 'Calendars',
      # 'CalendarsWriteOnly',
       'Camera',
      # 'Contacts',
      # 'FaceID',
      # 'LocationAccuracy',
      # 'LocationAlways',
      # 'LocationWhenInUse',
      # 'MediaLibrary',
      # 'Microphone',
      # 'Motion',
      # 'Notifications',
       'PhotoLibrary',
      # 'PhotoLibraryAddOnly',
      # 'Reminders',
      # 'Siri',
      # 'SpeechRecognition',
      # 'StoreKit',
    ])

  target 'testTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
  end
end
````

Comment: please add pod file code here

Comment: Added podfile!!!!